# Is whether there is a complete negatively curved surface embedded in the unit ball still an open problem?

Tags: geometry, curves, spheres

I was reading the text "Open problems in geometry of curves and surfaces" by Mohammad Ghomi, and on page 15 Problem 7.2 asks "are there any complete negatively curved surfaces embedded in the unit ball?"

I tried googling to search for solutions to this problem, but was only able to find general definitions of complete negatively curved surfaces unrelated to the problem in this question.

Is this still an open problem?

Comment: Try googling Nadirashvili surfaces. I believe they answer your question (although I don't understand the subject well enough to say whether its in the negative or positive direction).

Comment: @QC_QAOA: Nadirashvili's surfaces are only immersed, not embedded. They are specifically mentioned in Ghomi's survey.

Comment: Ghomi's survey is from September of the 2019 (last revision). Is there any reason to expect that the problem was settled in the last 6 months or that Ghomi would not know about an earlier solution? (He is a senior and quite serious research mathematician.)

Comment: @MoisheKohan not as far as I'm aware, I just wanted to be sure.  Please make this an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Ah, that was what I could find with a semi-intensive google search. My mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest [update](https://people.math.gatech.edu/~ghomi/Papers/op.pdf) of Ghomi's list of open problems  is from September of the 2019 and the problem is still listed as open. If it was solved in the last 6 months, Ghomi probably would have updated his survey (and, most likely, the word of a solution would be out). Thus, you can safely assume that the problem is currently open. (I would **not** recommend to work on this problem though, unless you are an established mathematician who can afford to spend time tackling a well-known open problem, or if you are comparable, in the sense of mathematical strength and maturity, to John Pardon, when he was an undergrad in Princeton.)

One more thing: If you check Mathoverflow discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52851/the-geometry-of-nadirashvilis-complete-bounded-negative-curvature-surface), you might get an impression from Tom Mrowka's answer that Hadamard's problem was solved by Colding and Minicozzi in 2008. This is not the case. What they proved is that a complete embedded **minimal** surface of negative curvature in $E^3$ must be unbounded. But Hadamard's problem was about arbitrary surfaces, not minimal ones. One can say that they proved that Nadirashvili-type examples  cannot be embedded.

Comment: I have nothing but time and curiosity, so I think this will be a good problem to study for some time.